# android how to display app logo on my data path folder

Tags: android, custom-controls, graphical-logo

I want to display my app logo displays in data folder like this

[image]

Comment: what do u mean by layout? Which layout do u want to analyze?

Comment: check this link,http://www.exploretheandroid.net/2014/05/how-to-show-app-icon-on-folders-in-es.html

Comment: Can you explain where do you want this please ?

Comment: @Jignesh Jain thank u so much, it works well, if u answer i would be check as accepted. "I'm very grateful to you for all your help"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply follow this link it will help you,

http://www.exploretheandroid.net/2014/05/how-to-show-app-icon-on-folders-in-es.html